# Matching characters in two Python strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to print the shared characters between 2 sets of strings in Python, I am doing this with the hopes of actually finding how to do this using nothing but python regular expressions (I don't know regex so this might be a good time to learn it).

So if `first_word = "peepa"` and `second_word = "poopa"` I want the return value to be: `"pa"`
since in both variables the characters that are  shared are p and a. So far I am following the documentation on how to use the re module, but I can't seem to grasp the basic concepts of this.

Any ideas as to how would I solve this problem?

Comment: What if the second word was `pooblapa`? Would you still want it to match `pa`? I.e. are the parts only supposed to match when they appear at the same location? Also, what about the `p` at the beginning of both words? Please give some more examples. Also forget using regular expressions here; won’t work.

Comment: Would it be possible to treat each string as a set of characters, and find the intersection of these sets?

Comment: @poke in there then the matching would be "opa" since what I am trying to do is make all of the characters that are shared in both strings to be printed.

Comment: @rayryeng I guess it would be possible and simpler, more than anything I want to get a feel for doing something like this with regular expressions. But other have already said that this would not work, I am in no position to argue that since I have little understanding of how regular expressions work.

Comment: @Alex_adl04 - Regular expressions are meant to find patterns in a string, given an input pattern.  They're not designed to find what is common between two separate strings... I think you're SOL here using `regex` :(

Comment: @rayryeng Thank for clarifying that for me ray. I just thought that this would be a good chance to learn more about regex, the problem does not need to be solved that way, this was a big noob moment of mine since I tried to solve something with a specific tool that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Alex_adl04 - I spoke too soon.  It looks like someone showed you how to do it using `regex`, but they used `sub`.  It almost does what you want, but there are some duplicates in the matching.  BTW, don't worry about feeling n00b at all.  All of us have been at that point... and I'll be the first to admit that I've had my fair share of those experiences too!  It's always nice to try to think of completely new ways to solve things.  That's how most things got invented... it always starts with trying to push out of the boundaries of what we already know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a problem where you want to find the intersection of characters between the two strings.  The quickest way would be to do this:

```
>>> set(first_word).intersection(second_word)
set(['a', 'p'])
```

I don't think regular expressions are the right fit for this problem.

Comment: I really like this, but can you explain why you don't have to use set() on second_word?

Comment: The `intersection` method of sets takes an iterable as an argument. Strings are iterable.

Comment: this is actually very useful,I had thought of finding a way around this with set after regular expressions proved little to no result. I did not think of using intersection though. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use sets. Casting a string to a set returns an iterable with unique letters. Then you can retrieve the intersection of the two sets.

```
match = set(first_word.lower()) & set(second_word.lower())
```

Comment: Hahaha, this came right after I left my comment.  Awesome.  +1

Answer (score 2):

#### Using regular expressions

This problem is tailor made for sets.  But, you ask for "how to do this using nothing but python regular expressions."

Here is a start:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^peepa]', '', "poopa")
'ppa'
```

The above uses regular expressions to remove from "poopa" every letter that was not already in "peepa".  (As you see it leaves duplicated letters which sets would not do.)

In more detail, `re.sub` does substitutions based on regular expressions.  `[peepa]` is a regular expression that means any of the letters `peepa`.  The regular expression `[^peepa]` means anything that is not in `peepa`.  Anything matching this regular expression is replaced with the empty string `""`, that is, it is removed.  What remains are only the common letters.

Comment: I see, this is a great example. Since I am trying to stick to convention and best practices I will then set my attention to the use of the function set(no pun intended). Thank you for the great example John